# Missing last character with SwiftUI Textifeld

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just ran into a pretty awkward issue while using a TextField() in SwiftUI. All I'm trying to do is to pass the data from the textfield to a class (that's marked with @ObservableObject). In this class, there's a function called displayData() that just prints out the data that got passed by the textfield. I'd say 70% of the time, the last character of the string is missing. What bugs me here is that **it doesn't occur all the time.** It makes it pretty hard to figure it out.

To give you an example, if I type 1234 say in the first TextField(), print(self.username) will return 123. When I try to add a second 4, it prints out 12344.

Both the TextField() and the SecureField() are having this problem.

That's what's going on int the ContentView

```
            TextField("Enter your username here.", text: self.$dataManager.username)
                .padding()
            SecureField("Enter your password here.", text: self.$dataManager.password)
                .padding()
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.dataManager.displayData()
            }, label: {
                Text("Send Data")
            }).padding()
            Spacer()
```

And in the class:

```
var username: String = ""
var password: String = ""

func displayData(){
        print("USERNAME: \(self.username), PASSWORD: \(self.password)")
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this view create that `dataManager` instance or is it created elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your `username` and `password` properties to correctly bind to your fields, you need to annotate them with `@Published` in your `ObservableObject`.

The following version works and doesn't suffer from the issues you mention:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var username = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    
    func displayData(){
        print("USERNAME: \(self.username), PASSWORD: \(self.password)")
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject var dataManager = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter your username here.", text: self.$dataManager.username)
            .padding()
        SecureField("Enter your password here.", text: self.$dataManager.password)
            .padding()
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            self.dataManager.displayData()
        }, label: {
            Text("Send Data")
        }).padding()
        Spacer()
    }
}
```